# three.js EffectComposer's render target

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I know that when we use an EffectComposer the scene is rendered into composer.renderTarget2 or composer.renderTarget1.
In this [example](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_postprocessing_ssao.html) I read this :

```
renderer.render( scene, camera, composer.renderTarget2, true );

renderer.shadowMapEnabled = false;
depthPassPlugin.enabled = false;

// do postprocessing

composer.render( 0.1 );
```

So what is the effect of the first line ? The scene is rendered into composer.renderTarget2 but how renderTarget2 is used then ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

renderTarget2 is a WebGLRenderTarget which specified the filter to use.
Then the rendering runs the composer's passes.

useful example: http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-animated-selective-glow.html

Comment: Wasn't me, but it might have been because the linked demo is nonfunctional :/

Comment: I think that's because the composer API has changed. I've found a number of three.js postprocessing/masking demos that no longer work